# How do I set multiple lines to my tooltip text for Material UI IconButton?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use material UI's IconButton component with a tooltip attribute. However, my tooltip value is a long string. How do I set my string to read on multiple lines instead of just one line for the tooltip pop up text?

```
const longSentenceForToolTop = "this is a really long tip and I would like to set it to multiple lines so I do not have one really long line as my tip going across my view because that would be obnoxious"

<IconButton
  tooltip={longSentenceForToolTop}
  tooltipPosition="top-center">
  <FontIcon
    className="material-icons">
    info_outline
  </FontIcon>
</IconButton>
```

Update:

My code looks like the following:

```
const toolTipText = (text) => (
  <div style={{lineHeight: 15px, whiteSpace: pre}}>
  </div>
);

   <IconButton
      tooltip={tipText(text)}
      tooltipPosition="top-center">
      <FontIcon
        className="material-icons">
        info_outline
      </FontIcon>
    </IconButton>
```

Now the text is broken up on its different lines but floats over the icon and not above it. I'm trying to use CSS to position the text above the icon, and I am not succeed. Does anyone know how to manipulate the position of an element with position: relative set?

Comment: I found this solution to be a great one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62116448/8925804

Answer (score 26):

You can put any element you want inside of `tooltip`, not just text:

```
<IconButton
  tooltip={<div>First Line<br />Second Line</div>}
  tooltipPosition="top-center">
  <FontIcon
    className="material-icons">
    info_outline
  </FontIcon>
</IconButton>
```

If you're not sure how long the `tooltip` will be and you want to force line breaks, you can use set the `width` of the div and force word wrapping (you can also force text align to the left in you don't want it centered):

```
<IconButton
  tooltip={
    <div style={{ width: 100, whiteSpace: 'normal', textAlign: 'left' }}>This is a very long tooltip</div>
  }
  tooltipPosition="top-center">
  <FontIcon
    className="material-icons">
    info_outline
  </FontIcon>
</IconButton>
```

Comment: styling the div within the tooltip helped. I used the whiteSpace property with 'pre' to position the line breaks, one after the other. Right now I have a different challenge however. The message pops up completely over the icon and not above it. Moreover, I am struggling with positioning the message above the icon element.

Answer (score 21):

For a one (or two) off, here is an inline style.

Separate your info with `\n` and put it inside a div with the `white-space` property set to `pre-line`.

```
const infoItems = ["line one", "line two"]
const tip = infoItems.join('\n')

<Tooltip
    title={
        <div style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}>{tip}</div>
    }
>
    <IconButton/>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can create a new class like `line-break` and then add the css property `white-space: pre-line` so that `\n` is interpreted as a line break.
Here is a quick example:

https://codepen.io/yowakita/pen/VPNxBV

In your specific case, you can inline the `whiteSpace` into the style property of the `IconButton`.

```
const text = 'Hello, this is line one \n and this is line 2';
  return 
    <IconButton
      style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-line'}}
      tooltip={text}
      tooltipPosition="top-center">
      <FontIcon
        className="material-icons">
        info_outline
      </FontIcon>
    </IconButton>
```

*Edit:* Seems like this didn't work for you- try placing the string into a `div` with the inline styling and then passsing it as a node to the `tooltip` property of `IconButton`.

```
const text = <div style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-line'}}>{'Hello, this is line one \n and this is line 2'}</div>;
  return 
    <IconButton
      tooltip={text}
      tooltipPosition="top-center">
      <FontIcon
        className="material-icons">
        info_outline
      </FontIcon>
    </IconButton>
```

Note that the `tooltip` property for the `IconButton` in material-ui is a **node** type, so it can take in numbers, strings, elements or an array (or fragment) containing these types.

So instead of passing in a long string you could also pass in another component/element, such as a set of divs that split up that long string of text:

```
const longSentenceForToolTop = 
  <div>
    <div>this is a really long tip and I would like to set it</div>
    <div>to multiple lines so I do not have one really long</div> 
    <div>line as my tip going across my view because that would</div>
    <div>be obnoxious</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: this is a great suggestion however the one that has \n get interpreted as a line break is not having any effect -- all the text is still one line. Regarding your other suggestion, it does work in the sense that now I have multiple lines in the tool tip text. However, when I hover around the icon the popup tooltip text appears -- this is incorrect behavior. The text should only appear when my mouse hovers over the icon and not on the html for `longSentenceForToolTip`

Comment: I have updated my comment with another way to insert the text as a node with an inline-styled div. Regarding the problems with the second approach, note that Material Design guidelines suggest that Tooltips stay concise and not have rich content. Not adhering to these principles can cause unexpected rendering of your Material-UI components. https://material.io/guidelines/components/tooltips.html#tooltips-usage

Answer (score 4):

First, know that you can put anything you want in a title -- including additional JSX.

That said, as a quick-and-dirty solution for future people running into this question: you can just provide a `span` and place an array of your text lines inside it, separated by `break` tags.

Like so:

```
<Tooltip title={<span>{["Line one.",<br />,"Line two."]}</span>}>
    <Typography>XXXX</Typography>
</Tooltip>
```

Will provide a tooltip like this:
[image: Two Line Tooltip]