# Is it possible to add icon inside Material UI Tooltip?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is my code. I have tried to use the material icon(PhoneInTalk) inside Tooltip's title attribute. But my process seems not working.
Here is my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAVdP.png)

```js
//@material-ui/core/styles
const CustomTooltip = withStyles({
  tooltip: {
    color: "tomato",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "12px",
  },
})(Tooltip);

//JSX
<CustomTooltip
        title={`${(<PhoneInTalk />)} Let's talk`}
        placement="top-end"
        arrow
        >
<Avatar className={classes.avatar} src={avatar} alt="Ibrahim Kaiser" />
</CustomTooltip>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try enclosing the icon and text in a fragment.

```
<CustomTooltip
    title={<><PhoneInTalk /> Let's talk</>}
    placement="top-end"
    arrow
>
```

Check this example sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-18wby?file=/demo.tsx)